# Why answer an “Picture only” question?

Tags: discussion, new-users

I feel more and more questions are sent with pictures only and no code. See;

[NonlinearModelFit errors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77751/nonlinearmodelfit-errors)

[Including error bars on graph in Mathematica [duplicate]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77498/including-error-bars-on-graph-in-mathematica/77516#comment210403_77516)

Why should I care for such questions? I have a bad feeling to answer questions that show little respect for the community and the practice. But I want to help beginners, as the community helps me again and again.

Can we as for the Q&A [Standard greeting comments](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/standard-greeting-comments) create a catalog that brings inexperienced or lazy users users to the right path and shows them suitable directions?

Which word choice or tips or evidence would you provide?

PS: Links i like, [What are the qualities of a good Question?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/what-are-the-qualities-of-a-good-question), [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently), [Standard greeting comments](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/standard-greeting-comments)